# Multiple volume change using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I have an html file with few audio tags. They have id which I can't change and class name. How can I change volume at same time of all these audio elements by one `input type="range"`

```
<!-- want to change volume of all above audio -->    
<audio id="player_btn_0_0" class="Player" src="1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="player_btn_0_1" class="Player" src="2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="player_btn_0_2" class="Player" src="3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="player_btn_1_0" class="Player" src="4.MP3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="player_btn_1_1" class="Player" src="5.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="player_btn_1_2" class="Player" src="6.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="player_btn_2_0" class="Player" src="7.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="player_btn_2_1" class="Player" src="8.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="player_btn_2_2" class="Player" src="9.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<input type="range" name="Volume Changer" id="volume">

<!-- Dont want to change volume in this file -->    
<audio id="SUper" class="megaPlayer" src="666.mp3" preload="none" loop="" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

Ideal solution: if I can use class name to change volume. something like:

```
 $('.Player').volume = $('#volume').value/100;
```

But it doesn't work.

Here is fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zg3dtez5/2/ , I put play/pause function for example how I work with this audio.

Answer by using jQuery:

```
$('.Player').prop('volume',volume.value/100);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written example in your jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zg3dtez5/1/

```
var volumeRange = $("#volume");
volumeRange.change(function() {
    $("audio").attr("volume", (volumeRange.val() / 100));
});
```

Comment: this solutions isnt suitable for me, I have one more audio where I dont want change volume. I just added some changes on first post.And also I cant change volume of audio by attribut volume="float".

Comment: So remove that element from the collection: `$('audio').not('#Super').attr(...);` (assuming the `id` of `'SUper'` is a typo).

Comment: Ok, have solution. audio tag didnt work with volume atribute. Volume is audio tag property. And you need to change attr to prop.